# What stops water from stagnating in a gutter drain line that has a pop-up emitter?

Tags: plumbing, drainage, gutters

I'm planning on burying some rigid PVC pipe to attach guttering on my house to a few pop-up emitters like this:

[image: Pop up drain emitter]

But the pop-up emitter makes a right angle UP, so doesn't that mean that basically the entire buried pipe will remain filled with stagnating water? It seems like this would be normal but I'm not sure if this causes smell issues or any other adverse effects.

Comment: Are there any holes in the pipe? If not poke a few and any water will drain and not become stagnant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used a post hole digger and made a small leech pit right under the 90 on mine. Filled it with gravel and drilled a 3/8" hole in the bottom of the 90. After it rains the water can drain out and absorb into the dirt.

Comment: Great suggestion, sounds totally reasonable, thanks!

Comment: So.....when I say small I mean small in relative terms. Small for a typical leech line/field. I dug a hole 3' down and that seems to have worked fine over the last 6-7 years. I'm sure it will eventually clog with shingle silt and dirt, but will be relatively easy to dig back and start over with clean gravel.

Comment: The fittings are not watertight anyway, so even without holes the water eventually empties.

Comment: Do those right angle fittings have a knockout to make a hole?

Comment: Not that I've ever seen. Have to drill a hole in it.